# Can the default lifestyle of Castle Windsor registered components be changed?

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

The [Castle Windsor documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md#singleton) shows that Singleton is the default lifestyle for registered components.

Is it possible to change the default lifestyle such that by default, a registered component will have a transient lifestyle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if possible or not but what you can do is add an "IContributeComponentModelConstruction" to set all components to a specific lifestyle.

Check this: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/26/ChangingWindsorlifestylesafterthefact/

Comment: It appears as though this is indeed the best option as of the time of writing. I hope that this is something we get to do in the future :).